# Reading from JSON generated by Import.io, with jQuery (accessing a key with a slash in its name)

Tags: jquery, json, import.io

I am having difficulties with accessing a value because its key contains a forward slash in its name.

Here's an excerpt of the JSON that's returned by Import.io:

```
"results":[  
  {  
     "superawesome_link":"https://medium.com/@sprawsmdoo",
     "graf_image":"https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/fit/t/800/240/1*YIWxXylsoUQIDfQK353YuA.png",
     "avatar_link":"https://medium.com/@sprawsmdoo",
     "darken_link/_text":"Jan 28",
     "readmore_number":10.0,
     "readmore_number/_source":"10",
     "readingtime_value_numbers/_source":"7",
     "readmore_link":"https://medium.com/@sprawsmdoo/pricing-design-services-bca1c6955b47?source=latest---------1",
     "readingtime_value_numbers":7.0,
     "readmore_link/_text":"Read more…",
     "darken_link":"https://medium.com/@sprawsmdoo/pricing-design-services-bca1c6955b47?source=latest---------1",
     "postarticle_link/_text":"Pricing design servicesWhat we’re doing, how we’re doing it, and what we’re struggling with when it…",
     "readingtime_value":"7 min read",
     "postarticle_link":"https://medium.com/@sprawsmdoo/pricing-design-services-bca1c6955b47?source=latest---------1",
     "superawesome_link/_text":"Superawesome"
  },
...
```

And here's the jQuery code I am using to access the data:

```
var mediumJSON = "URLHERE";

$.ajax({
  url: mediumJSON,
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    $.each(response.results, function(index, value) {
      var newPost = $("#postTemplate").clone();
      newPost.appendTo('.posts');
      newPost.removeAttr('id');
      newPost.find('.post-title a').attr('href', value.readmore_link).text(value.postarticle_link/text);
      newPost.find('.post-length').text(value.readingtime_value);
      newPost.show();
      return index < 4;
    });
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $('.posts').html('<article class="post"><div class="quiet">There was an error fetching posts, you can read our blog <a href="https://medium.com/@sprawsmdoo">directly on Medium</a>.</div></article>');
  }
});
```

The following bit is giving me problems because of the slash:

```
.text(value.postarticle_link/text)
```

The error message is "Uncaught ReferenceError: text is not defined".

How can I reference `postarticle_link/text` in order to get its value?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation), It allows access to properties containing special characters.

```js
var data = {          
     "readmore_number":10.0,
     "readmore_number/_source":"10",
     "superawesome_link/_text":"Superawesome"
  }

alert(data['superawesome_link/_text'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you used import.io's "Magic". You could simply use their [App](https://www.import.io/download) and build a new Extractor. This way you could point & click the data you want, change the data type (link or text) and give the resulting data column a name you want (without slashes).